# Norm with maximum of coefficients on polynomial ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

> Given a non-archimedean normed field $(F,|\cdot|)$, show we can extend the norm to $F[x]$ by setting $|a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n|\mapsto \max(|a_0|,|a_1|,\ldots,|a_n|).$

I am having trouble showing the multiplicativity of this extended norm. We have to show that
\begin{equation*}
\max_k \left\vert \sum_{i+j=k} a_ib_j \right\vert=\max_i |a_i|\cdot \max_j |b_j|.
\end{equation*}
Since $|-|$ is non-archimedean, we have
$$
\left\vert \sum_{i+j=k} a_ib_j \right\vert\leq \max_{\substack{i,j \\ i+j=k}} |a_i | |b_j| \leq \max_{i,j}|a_i| |b_j|=\max_i |a_i|\cdot \max_j |b_j|.
$$
Taking $\max_k$ on both sides gives one equality of what we need to show. However, I need to inspect when equalities occur.

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: look at the largest $i$ such that $a_i$ achieves the norm of $f$ and similarly for $b$.  Then the sum you wrote that includes their product has a unique term achieving the maximum.  Next, use the properties of a norm.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Then the sum you wrote that includes their product has a unique terms achieving the maximum" ?

Comment: I wrote an answer below, I ended up using the minimum index, but there is a symmetric proof with the largest index that I mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
f=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_nx^n
$$
and
$$
g=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\dots+b_mx^m.
$$
Let $r$ be the smallest index such that $|a_r|=|f|$ and $s$ be the smallest index such that $|b_s|=|g|$.

Now, consider $|fg|$.  In particular, let's look at $|(fg)_{r+s}|$.  As you note,
$$
(fg)_{r+s}=\sum_{i=0}^{r+s}a_ib_{r+s-i}.
$$
We observe that $|a_rb_s|=|f||g|$.  Moreover, for $i\not=r$, $|a_ib_{r+s-i}|<|f||g|$ by the assumptions on $r$ and $s$ (either $i<r$ or $r+s-i<s$).  One of the properties of non-Archimedean norms states when the norm of a sum is equal to the maximum norm of the summands, this is exactly the current case.

Comment: Regarding the answer. How do we use that $(fg)_{rs}=\sum a_ib_{r+s-i}$ and $|a_ib_{r+s-i}|<|f||g|$ to conclude that $|fg|=|f||g|$? @Torsten Schoeneberg

Comment: @user726608:  As written, by the ultrametric maximum principle this shows $\lvert f \rvert \lvert g\rvert = \lvert (fg)_{r+s} \rvert$. Which implies $\lvert f \rvert \lvert g \rvert \le \max_{0\le i \le m+n} \lvert (fg)_i \rvert =: \lvert fg \rvert$. The reverse inequality was shown in the question.